# Mask a stars object in R

Tags: r, stars

I am trying to mask a stars object in R, but not sure how to do it. The documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stars/vignettes/stars6.html) says that `mask` in Raster can be done as `[] <-` in stars. I am not sure what this means.

Here is code from the raster package to mask an object.

```
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
m <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r)) * 10
values(m) <- runif(ncell(r))
m[m < 0.5] <- NA
mr <- mask(r, m)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's convert your rasters to stars objects:

```
> rs = st_as_stars(r)
> ms = st_as_stars(m)
```

Then you either do this on `rs` directly or like this, make a new copy in `mrs`:

```
> mrs = rs
```

Then set the elements of `mrs` that match `NA` in `ms` to NA:

```
> mrs[is.na(ms)] = NA
```

and plot:

```
> plot(mrs)
```

[image]

which looks (barring the colour) like your `plot(mr)`