# Mask a (raster) stars object in R with a vector (sf) object

Tags: raster, r, vector, terra, stars

In this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413979/mask-a-stars-object-in-r) an stars object is masked with a raster object. But it is not clear to me how the masking can be done with a vector object using the `stars` pkg.

Consider the following example in terra.

I want to mask `srtm` with `zion`:

```
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(stars)

#   SpatRaster class from terra
srtm = rast(system.file("raster/srtm.tif", package = "spDataLarge"))

#   sf class from sf
zion = read_sf(system.file("vector/zion.gpkg", package = "spDataLarge"))
zion = st_transform(zion, crs(srtm))

#   Transforming sf class to SpatVector class from terra
zion_vect = vect(zion)

#   Masking in terra
srtm_masked = mask(srtm, zion_vect)
```

This produces the desired result
[image]

The `stars` documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stars/vignettes/stars6.html) says that `mask` in the `raster` package can be done as `[] <-` in `stars`, but using this with a `sf` object raises an error.

Converting `strm` to an stars object, `srtms = st_as_stars(srtm)`, and executing

```
srtms_masked <- srtms
srtms_masked[zion] <- srtms
```

I get an error

```
Error in `[<-.stars`(`*tmp*`, zion, value = list(srtm.tif = c(1728, 1718,  : 
  selector should be a stars object
```

So, I am not sure what `[] <-` means for masking with vector layer.

In particular, I’m looking for the translation of

```
## S4 method for signature 'SpatRaster,SpatVector'
mask(x, mask, inverse=FALSE, updatevalue=NA,
    touches=TRUE, filename="", ...)
```

from `terra` to `stars`, where the `touches` option can be important.

Comment: Can you edit your question to create some sample objects for this? So you can then say "I want to mask this `x` with this `y`" without us having to create our own `x` and `y`. Will save us a bit of trouble and make your question more likely to be answered.

Comment: Done it! Completely rewritten, with an example.

Comment: Am not sure the docs are right so opened an issue: https://github.com/r-spatial/stars/issues/550

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting your terra object to stars and then subsetting by your `sf` `zion` object seems to work:

```
srtms = st_as_stars(srtm)
plot(srtms[zion])
```

You never actually gave the line of code you said didn't work, but said something about `[] <-` which would be some kind of replacement operation. Anyway, the expression `srtms[zion]` returns a masked stars object.

[image]

Weirdly the documentation seems to imply that this should be an "extract" operation, returning the values of the raster in the polygon, but it doesn't do that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the issue and the help. I have added to the main question the line of code that gave me an error. Also it is not clear how the masked object, `srtms[zion]`, handles the border cells, the `touches` option in `maks`.